# Getting buttons inside tableview

Tags: ios

I want to add button inside **UITableView** with drag and drop but i don't know how to call them inside **UITableviewCell**.You can see a keyword **Desc** where I have to set them as button title so that I can get all values which I placed in coreData frameWork.

```
-(void)setquestions:(int)qid
{
    NSManagedObject *singleobject = nil;
    singleobject = AllQuestions[qid];

    NSString * desc=[singleobject valueForKey:@"questionDesc"];
    questionlabel.text=desc;

    int qidns=[[singleobject valueForKey:@"questionId"]intValue];

    NSArray *dummy=[self getoptions:qidns];

    NSLog(@"--inside setquestion-%lu",(unsigned long)dummy.count);

    for (int i=0; i<dummy.count; i++) {
        NSManagedObject *singleobject = nil;
        singleobject = dummy[i];
        NSString * desc=[singleobject valueForKey:@"optionDesc"];
        [self addbutton:desc bid:i];
    }
}

-(void)addbutton:(NSString *)desc bid:(int)bid{
    [[QBFlatButton appearance] setFaceColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[QBFlatButton appearance] setSideColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    optionButton = [QBFlatButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    optionButton.faceColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f];
    optionButton.sideColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f];
    optionButton.radius = 4.0;
    optionButton.margin = 4.0;
    optionButton.depth = 3.0;
    [optionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    optionButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    optionButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    // you probably want to center it
    optionButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    optionButton.tag=bid;
    [optionButton setTitle:desc forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    optionButton.frame = CGRectMake(5,bid*55,optionsview.frame.size.width-10, 50);
    [optionsview addSubview:optionButton];
}

- (void)logItems {
    int index = 0;
    for ( NSString *str in self.items ) {
        NSLog(@"%d: %@", index++, str);
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Edit Mode
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; // No Delete icon
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [table deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Can move cell
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSUInteger origins = sourceIndexPath.row;  // Original position
    NSUInteger to = destinationIndexPath.row; // Destination position
    NSLog(@"Origin %lu, To %lu", (unsigned long)origins, (unsigned long)to);
    NSString *swap = [self.items objectAtIndex:origin];// Item
    [swap shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren];
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough for an answer. First make the question a bit more clear to get proper answers.

Comment: I need to call the button inside UItableViewCell with a title Desc simple as that....please  go through the program and juz by reading question you wont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from the question you want to get the button in the cell for that you can create a custom cell class and then call this custom cell inside the cellforrow function. You can call the button like this

customCell.button.title = "some-string"

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom button with a particular action added to each of the cells, first you need to create a custom UI cell(using XIB since you need to drag and drop). Then add the button to that, and connect the button's `IBAction` and `IBOutlet` to the custom subclass for the cell. Next Add a protocol with a function to the cell subclass so that you can send a callback to the ViewController when the button is clicked. Now implement the delegate in the ViewController and use this cell for your purpose. If the delegate function returns the cell, you can figure out which cell's button is clicked, hence getting the `indexpath` to perform required action.